# Shortest path in a graph

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory, path-finding

Write a program to take a graph (from either standard input or a file, your choice) and find a shortest path in the graph.

Graphs are specified using the following format:

```
A---S   F--T
|  / \  |
| /   5 0
|/     \|
D----3--E

    A-Z: nodes in the graph
   -|/\: edges in the graph
    0-9: weights on the edges
<space>: all the holes
```

All edges are undirected and lie along one of the 8 cardinal directions (i.e., no bends).  Edges may optionally contain a weight from 0 to 9.  The weight will not be on the last symbol that connects the edge to a node (i.e. edges need to have at least 3 symbols to contain a weight).  Unweighted edges have a default weight of 1.

Your code should compute the shortest path between nodes `S` and `T` and print the length and the path, like this:

```
5:SDEFT
```

Shortest correct program wins.

Comment: Puzzles, where you must write the **shortest** code outputing the **best output** have a problem: they can be solved by generation random outputs until it suits the task. So such puzzles better should have not the **shortest** solution but the **fastest**. But shortest path in graph is trivial, so no sense of **fastest**, then you may specify, that you want to get the **shortest solution with complexity of O(<???)** or maybe some another way to determine goal effectiveness.

Comment: I'm looking for the shortest program.  Go ahead and randomly generate solutions and test them if you think that will get you a shorter program.  Keep in mind your program must always be correct.

Comment: Does the graph diagram have to be parsed or can you use your own format? One example of a format - your graph could be represented as: `AS0,SD0,SE5,DE3,FE0,FT0` (you could omit the commas if each entry is 3 bytes long.)

Comment: Algorithm wise, an MST or Dijkstra comes to mind.

Comment: Yes, you have to parse the graph as I specified.  That's most of the problem, actually.  The shortest path part just makes sure your parsing is correct.

Comment: The input format is really far too complicated and imho doesn't really add that much to the problem.

Comment: Just thought folks here would like to try something a bit more challenging.

Comment: Differences in character widths could possibly ruin the alignment, especially across different fonts. For this reason, I agree that the input format is too complicated.

Comment: @SimpleCoder: I would assume monospace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my code, 494 characters in python:

```
import sys,re
m=sys.stdin.readlines()
Z=lambda c,s:re.findall(r'(\w)%s+(\d*)[^\w]*(\w)'%c,''.join(x*2for x in s))
T=lambda n:''.join(x for a in map(None,*n)for x in a if x)
E=Z('-',''.join(m))+Z('\\|',T(m))+Z('/',T(' '*m.index(s)+s for s in m))+Z('\\\\',T(' '*m[::-1].index(s)+s for s in m))
E+=[x[::-1]for x in E]
S={}
for x in E:S[x[0]]=1e9
S['S']=0
P={}
for i in E:
 for x,w,y in E:
  w=int('1'+w)%10
  if S[y]>S[x]+w:S[y]=S[x]+w;P[y]=x
i=p='T'
while i!='S':i=P[i];p=i+p
print'%d:'%S['T']+p
```