# The Truck Problem

Tags: popularity-contest, sorting, puzzle-solver, path-finding

I am a teacher who was given a problem a few years ago. Every year since I have given it to my advanced students as a bonus assignment, but in ~10 years only 8 solved it, each with a slightly different approach. The problem is as follows:

You have some input **(from stdin)**, in the following format (the `//comments` are not included in the input):

```
6      //Route Begin
1 2    //Route data...
1 3
3 4
3 5
4 6
5 6
2 3
2 4
0 0    //Route end
4      //Route Begin
2 3    //Route Data...
3 4
5 1
1 6
7 8
8 9
2 5
5 7
3 1
1 8
4 6
6 9
0 0    //Route end
// continued...
```

The input begins with the destination, an integer. It is followed by a 'map' of all streets in the city. Each line represents a connection, so you can get from street 1 to street 2, and vice-versa. On every rout you start at street 1, then work your way to your destination.

**The objective:** List all possible routes, and tell the user the shortest one (least amount of street changes).
Also, the code beads to be human readable.
 So you would wont to output something like:

```
Destination 1 (6):
1 2 3 4 6
1 2 3 5 6
1 2 4 3 5 6
1 2 4 6
1 3 2 4 6
1 3 4 6
1 3 5 6
There are 7 routes from the truck station to street 6.
The shortest of these is the route "1 2 4 6", with 4 streets.

Destination 2 (4):
1 3 2 5 7 8 9 6 4
1 3 4
1 5 2 3 4
1 5 7 8 9 6 4
1 6 4
1 6 9 8 7 5 2 3 4
1 8 7 5 2 3 4
1 8 9 6 4
There are 8 routes from the truck station to street 4.
The shortest of these is the route "1 3 4", with 3 streets.
```

Now personally, I rather java or python (and java is preferred more), but I leave this open ended to my students, so they can choose any language they like.

The original document is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9fv7C5AiA8EU01GVGp1Uk51NXc/view?usp=sharing)

**HOW TO WIN:** Create the described program in a readable programming language, with the following criteria:
- Readable
- takes the input from the user(stdin/file)
- Is mildly easy to understand.

Comment: This is probably not a good challenge to be a [popularity-contest]; it works extremely well as a [code-golf]. It's not related to [sorting], either.

Comment: Note that this is a [tag:path-finding] problem. It's a lot like [this](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/153/9498).

Comment: @Justin And the river question, and the arrow question, and the loop question etc.

Comment: Also, while you mention Java and Python, their tags are not relevant to this question.

Comment: @justin I didn't wan't it to be a short answer. I lost my answer and don't want to figure it out again.

Comment: @tawilson there needs to be an objective winning criteria so perhaps forming it into a code-challenge could work

Comment: Welcome to Programming Puzzles & Code Golf! In spite of what the Q&A format may suggest, this site is for programming challenges, which require an objective winning criterion. A challenge cannot be both code golf (shortest code wins) and a popularity contest (most upvoted answer wins), since the criteria contradict each other.

Comment: I have fixed it

Comment: @tawilson You have added criteria, but they aren't objective. "Readable" and "Is mildly easy to understand" are identical and subjective. What if two answers are posted that both solve your problem? Then what? This site is a Q&A style, but the idea is to post challenges out there that people can solve whenever they come across it. Shortest code is a pretty good criteria, as it allows us to objectively find a winning answer. Most answerers have an un-minified version of their code as well, which they post along with an explanation.

Comment: I guess I am unfamiliar with this stack exchange website. How should I word it then?

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that a teacher for 10 years would take more than 5 minutes to solve this incredibly easy problem. I also find it incredibly worrying only 8 of your students managed to solve it.

Comment: Its a small High school. Also, I just haven't had the time to figure it out again. Besides, it is nice to see other ppls algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

**Javascript (1159)**

```js
function h(g,e){var b=[],d=0,c=null,f=0;g.split("\n").forEach(function(a){a=a.replace(/\s*\/\/.*?$/,"");switch(d){case 0:c={};f=a;d++;break;case 1:a=a.split(" "),"0"===a[0]&&"0"===a[1]?(b.push(c),a=[],k(f,c,null,null,a),e.push([f,a]),d=0):(c[a[0]]||(c[a[0]]=[]),c[a[1]]||(c[a[1]]=[]),c[a[0]].push(a[1]),c[a[1]].push(a[0]))}})}
function k(g,e,b,d,c){b||(b="1",d=[]);d.push(b);var f=[];if(g!=b){if(e[b].forEach(function(a){-1==d.indexOf(a)&&(a=k(g,e,a,d.slice(),c))&&f.push(a)}),f.length)return f}else return c.push(d),d}
(function(g,z){var e=[];h(g,e);e.forEach(function(b){document.write("Destination "+b[0]+z);var d=99,c=-1;b[1].forEach(function(b,a){document.write(b.join(", ")+z);b.length<d&&(d=b.length,c=a)});document.write("There are "+b[1].length+" routes from the fire station to street "+b[0]+z);document.write('The shortest of these is the route "'+b[1][c].join(" ")+'", with '+d+" streets"+z)})})("6      //Route Begin\n1 2    //Route data...\n1 3\n3 4\n3 5\n4 6\n5 6\n2 3\n2 4\n0 0    //Route end\n4      //Route Begin\n2 3    //Route Data...\n3 4\n5 1\n1 6\n7 8\n8 9\n2 5\n5 7\n3 1\n1 8\n4 6\n6 9\n0 0    //Route end\n// continued...\n","<br>");
```

notes:

- Just used "regular" javascript code, then minified it using Closure
  Compiler
- Route data embedded, could have been alot shorter without a "parser". That would mean the data should be JSON encoded ..

Unminified version (added per request):

```
function parseInput(input, data)
{
    var output = [];
    var lines = input.split("\n");
    var state = 0;
    var route = null;
    var routeDest = 0;
    lines.forEach(function(val){
        val = val.replace(/\s*\/\/.*?$/, "");

        switch(state)
        {
            case 0:
                route = {};
                routeDest = val;
                state++
            break;
            case 1:
                var conn = val.split(" ");
                if (conn[0] === "0" && conn[1] === "0")
                {
                    output.push(route);
                    var innerData = [];
                    calculateRoutes(routeDest, route, null, null, innerData);
                    data.push([routeDest, innerData]);
                    state = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!route[conn[0]])
                    {
                        route[conn[0]]=[]
                    }
                    if (!route[conn[1]])
                    {
                        route[conn[1]]=[]
                    }

                    route[conn[0]].push(conn[1]);
                    route[conn[1]].push(conn[0]);
                }
            break;
        }
    });

    return output;
}

function calculateRoutes(dest, data, curr, from, returnData)
{
    if (!curr)
    {
        curr = "1";
        from = [];
    }

    from.push(curr);

    var routes = [];

    if (dest != curr)
    {
        data[curr].forEach(function(val){
            if (from.indexOf(val) == -1)
            {
                var route = calculateRoutes(dest, data, val, from.slice(), returnData);
                if (route)
                {
                    routes.push(route);
                }
            }
        });

        if (routes.length)
        {
            return routes;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        returnData.push(from);
        return from;
    }
}

function printRoutes(routeInfo)
{
    var data = [];
    parseInput(routeInfo, data);

    data.forEach(function(val){
        console.log("Destination " + val[0]);
        var shortLen = 99;
        var shortId = -1;
        val[1].forEach(function(ele, id){
            console.log(ele.join(", "));
            if (ele.length < shortLen)
            {
                shortLen = ele.length;
                shortId = id;
            }
        });
        console.log("There are " + val[1].length + " routes from the fire station to street " + val[0]);
        console.log("The shortest of these is the route \"" + val[1][shortId].join(" ") + "\", with " + shortLen + " streets");
    });
}

var nl = "\n"

printRoutes("6      //Route Begin" + nl +
    "1 2    //Route data..." + nl +
    "1 3" + nl +
    "3 4" + nl +
    "3 5" + nl +
    "4 6" + nl +
    "5 6" + nl +
    "2 3" + nl +
    "2 4" + nl +
    "0 0    //Route end" + nl +
    "4      //Route Begin" + nl +
    "2 3    //Route Data..." + nl +
    "3 4" + nl +
    "5 1" + nl +
    "1 6" + nl +
    "7 8" + nl +
    "8 9" + nl +
    "2 5" + nl +
    "5 7" + nl +
    "3 1" + nl +
    "1 8" + nl +
    "4 6" + nl +
    "6 9" + nl +
    "0 0    //Route end" + nl +
    "// continued..." + nl);
```

The unminified version uses `console.log` for output instead of `document.write`. Because `document.write` gives a better experience as a code snippet than `console.log`.

Comment: Could I see the decompressed version?